Genexus Blob from Base64 - How to generate &File or put it on Screen wtih GX?
I have a Base64 String (image, png), and i can't show it on screen with &Blob variable on GeneXus.
And i can't populate a &File variable with this &Blob.
Example:
(The blob is a orange square).
&Blob.FromBase64String('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')
And these options doesn't work:
&File.FromBase64String()
&File.Source = &Blob
&Image.FromURL(PathToUrl(&Blob))
&Image = loadbitmap(&Blob)
Need help to:

Show it on screen with GeneXus.
Populate a &File variable to manipulate the image to AWS.


To show &Blob on screen with GeneXus.
You could use HTML with an TextBlock.
Or even populate the &File variable and do &Image.FromURL(&File.GetURI())
`Textblock1.Caption = Format(!"<img style='display:block; width:100px;height:100px;' id='base64image' src='data:image/jpeg;base64,%1' />" , &Blob.ToBase64String())`

Populate a &File variable to manipulate the image to AWS.
To populate a &File variable, you need to populate a Varchar variable first.
The code below, will generate the .tmp file on PrivateTempStorage, and you can manipulate your &File variable.
`&Blob.FromBase64String(&Base64String)`

`&PathVarchar = &Blob`

`&File.Source = &PathVarchar`

